# Changing the colour of a link that its title is "Contact Us"

Tags: css

I want that all link have the color white except of the `contact-us` link.
For this I'm trying this:

```css
    a {
  color: #fff;
  {
    a[title="Contact us"] {
      color: #000;
    }
```

```html
<a title="Contact Us" href="www.mydomain.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a>
```

But it's not working.
Is wrong what I'm trying?

Comment: the first curly bracket should be closed. Is it typo?

Comment: Two typos: wrong brace, wrong casing.

Answer (score 2):

The first curly bracket should be closed. Is it typo?

If yes, then you correctly declared style. However, it looks like you need to add more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to your anchor tag.

For example, if you have `div` and that `div` has an `a`, then you can add `div` before `a` and specificity will be higher:

```css
a {
    color: orange;
}


a[title="Contact us"] {
    color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://">Click Me 1</a>

<div>
    <a href="http://" title="Contact us">Click Me 2</a>
</div>
```

```
div a[title="Contact us"] {
color: #000;
}
```

Comment: @user1941537 I am glad that it helped to you! Try to avoid to use !important. It is not the best practise. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following css:

```
a[title="Contact us"] {
    color: #000 !important;
 }
```